# $q$-expansion of Klein's absolute invariant using infinite products

Tags: complex-analysis, infinite-product, q-series, modular-function

Given that
$$j=\frac{1}{13824q^2}\left(2^8q^2\prod_{k\gt 0}(1+q^{2k})^{16}+\prod_{k\gt 0}(1+q^{2k-1})^{16}+\prod_{k\gt 0}(1-q^{2k-1})^{16}\right)^3,$$
how can I show that
$$j=\frac{1}{1728q^2}(1+c_1 q^2+c_2 q^4+\cdots)$$
where $c_1,\, c_2,\, \ldots$ are some constants? I'm interested in the first term, i.e. $\frac{1}{1728q^2}$.

I tried expanding the product, which gives
$$j=\frac{1}{13824q^2}\left(2^{24}q^6\prod_{k\gt 0}(1+q^{2k})^{48}+3\cdot 2^{16}q^4\prod_{k\gt 0}(1+q^{2k})^{32}(1+q^{2k-1})^{16}+3\cdot 2^{16}q^4\prod_{k\gt 0}(1+q^{2k})^{32}(1-q^{2k-1})^{16}+3\cdot 2^{16}q^4\prod_{k\gt 0}(1+q^{2k})^{16}(1+q^{2k-1})^{32}+6\cdot 2^8q^2\prod_{k\gt 0}(1+q^{2k}-q^{4k-2}-q^{6k-2})^{16}+3\cdot 2^8 q^2\prod_{k\gt 0}(1+q^{2k})^{16}(1-q^{2k-1})^{32}+\prod_{k\gt 0}(1+q^{2k-1})^{48}+3\prod_{k\gt 0}(1+q^{2k-1})^{32}(1-q^{2k-1})^{16}+3\prod_{k\gt 0}(1+q^{2k-1})^{16}(1-q^{2k-1})^{32}+\prod_{k\gt 0}(1-q^{2k-1})^{48}\right).$$
Expanding doesn't seem to help.

But I know that the expression above can be written as
$$j=\frac{1}{13824}\frac{(\theta _2 ^8(0)+\theta _3 ^8(0)+\theta _4 ^8(0))^3}{q^2\prod_{k\gt 0}(1-q^{2k})^{24}}$$
where
$$\begin{align}\theta _2(0)&=2Pq^{\frac{1}{4}}\prod_{k\gt 0}(1+q^{2k})^2\\ \theta _3(0)&=P\prod_{k\gt 0}(1+q^{2k-1})^2\\ \theta _4(0)&=P\prod_{k\gt 0}(1-q^{2k-1})^2\end{align}$$
where $P=\prod_{k\gt 0}(1-q^{2k})$ and
$$\theta _2 ^8(0)+\theta _3 ^8(0)+\theta _4 ^8(0)=\frac{3}{\pi ^4}(e_1 ^2+e_2 ^2+e_3 ^2).$$
The symbol $q$ is the nome $e^{\pi i\frac{\omega _1}{\omega _2}}$ and $e_1=\wp \left(\frac{\omega _1}{2}\right)$, $e_2=\wp \left(\frac{\omega _2}{2}\right)$ and $e_3 =\wp \left(-\frac{\omega _1+\omega _2}{2}\right)$ for the Weierstrass's elliptic function $\wp$.

Comment: You're basically just checking $j$ is an even function of $q$, no?

Comment: @runway44 Why should that help?

Comment: A function has only even powers in its expansion if and only if it is an even function. (And similarly, it has only odd powers iff it's an odd function.)

Comment: @runway44 I know. I meant, how does the $\frac{1}{1728}$ at the beginning follow from that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write this as

$$ j=\frac{1}{13824q^2}\big(A(q)+B(q)+B(-q)\big)^3 $$

Notice every coefficient of $A$ is an even number and $A$ is an even function.

Moreover, $B(q)+B(-q)$ removes all odd powers from $B$'s expansion and doubles the remaining coefficients, so the same can be said for $B(q)+B(-q)$.

Therefore, we may rewrite this as

$$ j=\frac{1}{13824q^2}\big(2C(q^2)\big)^3 $$

for some power series $C$. Cancelling out $2^3$ yields $1728$ below.